# List time/date created, time/date modified, and file name for all files in subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory

I have a batch file to retrieve files from a shared workspace.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir "D:\Share" /a-d-h /b /s') do (
  for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%g in ('dir "%%f" /tc ^| findstr /C:"%%~nxf"') do (
    echo %%h,%%i,%%g,"%%~nf","%%~xf
    )
  )>>D:\test.csv
endlocal
```

I would like to modify the first four output columns to:

- Time Created HH:MM
- Date Created YYYY-MM.DD
- Last Modified HH:MM Last
- Modified YYYY-MM.DD

Apologies in advance as new to this, also open to any redesign if there is a better process.

Comment: The most important missing information is the format of the date and time that **you** have in `%%g`..`%%i`. This is user-dependent and may use different separators, elements, sequences and formats. (eg. `mm/dd/yy hh:mm a/pm` or `d/mm/yyyy h:mma/pm` and many other combinations). Next, you are not showing the last-modified datestamp field (`%%~tb`). What I'd suggest is to call an internal subroutine passing all of the required elements as parameters and process the strings into the required format and `echo` the result in that subroutine.

Comment: All of the manipulation and minefields have been covered before on SO and can be searched for using the facility in the top bar.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. New to this, wish I had more experience. I have combed through past solutions, but was having a challenge merging several ideas lines.

Comment: I understand time formats will differ, and was experimenting quite a bit, but could not get h/i variables defined or combined. I assumed if I could solve for created, I would be able to apply it to last-modified. Most of the above is based on a 2016 post, but I didn't realize the site was so big. I know it's prob dumb & obvs, but any tips or references would be welcome. Accountant here, but willing to work along and continue to try.

Comment: Accountant, eh? OK - I'll type slowly then. Suppose you had a `dir` list of a file that was dated August 5th, 2016 at 1:17pm. How would that file timestamp be displayed to you?

Comment: Yes, I greatly apologize! Much better with spreadsheets, but I try my best.

08/05/2016  01:17 PM                 0 file.txt

I tried to figure out delimiters, is this where we are headed? It would be neat to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f  "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b /s /a-d-h "xx.csv" ') DO (
 ECHO %%b
 FOR /f "tokens=1-3" %%g IN ('dir /tc "%%b"^|findstr /c:"%%~nxb"') DO (
  CALL :report %%g %%h %%i %%~tb "%%~nb" "%%~xb"
rem  CALL :report 04/30/2016 08:46 AM 08/05/2016 01:17 PM "%%~nb" "%%~xb"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF

:report
rem parameters are cdate ctime campm mdate mtime mampm name extension (cdate=createdate...)
rem datestamp format is 08/05/2016 01:17 PM for Aug. 5th 2016 @ 1:17pm
rem required output format
rem Time Created HH:MM Date Created YYYY-MM.DD Last Modified HH:MM Last Modified YYYY-MM.DD name extension

CALL :YYYY-MM.DD cdate %1
CALL :24hr ctime %2 %3
CALL :YYYY-MM.DD mdate %4
CALL :24hr mtime %5 %6

ECHO %ctime% %cdate% %mtime% %mdate% %~7 %~8
GOTO :eof

:: convert from mm/dd/yyyy to YYYY-MM.dd

:YYYY-MM.DD 
SET "raw=%2"
SET "%1=%raw:~-4%-%raw:~0,2%.%raw:~3,2%"
GOTO :eof

:: convert from hh:mm ampm to HH:MM

:24hr
SET "raw=%2"
rem Exx 00:17 -> 12:17; 01:17 -> 01:17; 12:17 -> 12:17; 13:17 -> 01:17
IF "%raw:~02%"=="12" (SET /a raw=100) ELSE (SET "raw=1%raw:~0,2%")
rem Exx 00:17 -> 100  ; 01:17 -> 101  ; 12:17 -> 100  ; 13:17 -> 101
IF /i "%3" == "PM" SET /a raw+=12
rem Exx 00:17 -> 100  ; 01:17 -> 101  ; 12:17 -> 112  ; 13:17 -> 113
SET "raw=%raw%%2"
rem Exx 00:17 -> 10012:17; 01:17 -> 10101:17; 12:17 -> 11212:17; 13:17 -> 11312:17
SET "%1=%raw:~1,2%%raw:~-3%"
GOTO :eof
```

For testing purposes, I targeted a single file and removed the appending to the report file.

The `:report` subroutine takes 8 parameters - two sets of [date time ampm] and the file's name and extension. The name and extension can potentially contain spaces, so should be quoted.

it converts the dates supplied to the required format using subroutines `:YYYY-MM.DD` for the date and `:24hr` for the time end `echo`es the results.

`:YYYY-MM.DD` is simple. It assigns the date provided as the second parameter to a temporary variable, then uses substringing to deliver the required string to the variable specified as the first parameter.

Substringing is covered by `set /?` from the prompt or many articles on SO. It's important to note that the first character in a string is character `0`, not `1`.

You should not use `temp` or `tmp` for a user-variable as BOTH of these variables contain the name of a directory used to store temporary files. In the early days, some people used `tmp` and others `temp` for this purpose, so setting both suits both groups and maintains compatibility.

`:24hr` is a little more complex. Again `%1` is used to specify the return variable name. Its schtick is to convert `12` as an hour number to `00` if the time is AM and leave it as `12` for PM. Other hours, add 12 for PM.

The gotcha here is that if left to its own devices, batch will suppress leading zeroes and regards a leading `0` as specifying the value as **octal**.

So - if the first 2 characters of the time are `12`, start with `100`, otherwise, start with `1` prepended to the hour (consequently, 09:xx would become `109`- valid decimal instead of `09` - invalid octal).

Then add 12 if the time is PM.

Append the original time field to the result, and pick the 2nd and third character with the last 3 for return to %1.

Since my date/time format is DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM, it will produce nonsense when processed by the `:report` routine, so I tested using a set of constants as I believe they would be presented on a MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm ampm system (now remmed-out)

Further thoughts

I got `wmic` to work on my Win11 system.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "filepath=c:\106x"
SET "Filename=withtrailsp.txt"

set "EscapedFilePath=%FilePath:\=\\%"

FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=." %%b IN (
 `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe DATAFILE where "name='%EscapedFilePath%\\%Filename%'" GET "CreationDate"^,"LastAccessed"^,"LastModified" /VALUE`
) DO IF "%%c" neq "" SET %%b 
SET la
SET cr
```

Since it seems that `wmic` is required in order to get seconds for `Created` then it'll take the same amount of time to get all of the time fields using `wmic` with the advantage that the format is ISO (at least it is for me)

Note that this snippet uses `delayedexpansion` and that the `\` in filepaths needs to be doubled. Note also that the commas in the fields list also need to be escaped. The filename is just one I knew had different create/modified/accessed dates.

Comment: Whoa just went to school! Reread for two hrs, notes (accountant lol):

-Test- works on replica file exactly like your rem line, also successfully tried other files & folders
-8 params- see 8, able to call ~db as ~9 too
-Date- makes sense, returns enumeration for date/time over here
-Substring/Tmp- still above my head, but I get first char is 0
-24hr- Neat math, see %1 picking 2nd/3rd & last 3, also neat using %i for PM to add 12; before posting, I did read a lot on suppressed zeros and experienced that in my early tests which seemed to confuse csv (hence 24hr req)

Comment: Curious:

1) Dir /tc returns variables of g=cdate=%1, h=ctime=%2%3, i=am/pm, yes? Is it bc ~tb is alrdy defined in For snyntax and would return its first 3 delimited segments of mod date; mod time; am/pm that it doesn't need to be tokens 4-6 and the call/report will apply those 3 segments directly to %4 %5 and %6 wo needing defined?

2) How can the same substring raw=%2 be used in set date and set time? Is it bc it is only temporary?

3) It struck me in trying to work through your 24hr soln, would it have been simpler to just output HH:MM AM/PM instead of convert to 24hr?

Comment: Last, and prob really dumb questions:

4) Experimenting in adding 10th and 11th variables broke the call/report, likely bc of the addtl/second variable digit, any tips?

5) No endlocal? [us accountants always have to close parentheses]

6) The goto's seemed to jump me around a bit until I read up on exiting the subroutine vs the full file, but still finding where to output to csv isn't obvious to my noob self, sigh.

Comment: Good day! After some further experimenting with your fantastic answer, I was able to export  via: )>>D:\test.csv, and call a new variable (9) with: ECHO %ctime%,%cdate%,%mtime%,%mdate%,%~7,%~8,%~9

I ran this on our Audit/Share directory and it worked perfectly. The goal is and was to use it to double check our audit staff in the field and their customer billing based on their document production.

Comment: One thing our back office team noticed is that sometimes our auditors will 'Save-As' and rename a document for customer delivery. That's def ok, but could be easier tracked with HH:MM:SS. Attempting to follow along, I tried the below, but it only repeated SS from MM. As mentioned, not my specialty, but unlike what I saw with using the %time variable are SS able to be extracted from dir /tc and for /%~tb?
My poor attempt and failed line:
SET "%1=%raw:~1,2%%raw:~5,3%%raw:~-3%"

Comment: I've been doing a little research into `how to get seconds for a file's timefields`. The solution for the last-modified time appears to be simple - `where filename` should produce that. Tradition wisdom is that `wmic` can be used to extract the time-fields (amongst other data).  The downsides to that are that `wmic` is SLOW and DEPRECATED. Naturally, `where` could be used for last-modified and `wmic` for the create-time. *In theory...* Deprecated? Unlikely to be removed IMHO - too many big users in industry. Not maitainde -more likely.

Comment: However - Using Win11, I've been unable to get wmic to work "as advertised" using `wmic DATAFILE where "name='filename'" GET CreationDate /VALUE` for instance. ('though `wmic` would typically return dates in  yyyymmddhhmmss format). More research on this is warranted, I believe...

Comment: Apologies for the delay, tax and audit season over here so late evenings in the office. Was quickly able to see last-mod seconds with - where filename. Great tip, thank you. Create-time seconds seems to both elude my research and also be above my pay grade. Our devices are 11 and 10 (from outsourced tech and support company). Enjoy the weekend!

Comment: Thank you for the further thoughts on wmic. With tax season behind us, I'll take a closer look.
Also, the back office team here wanted to pass along our sincerest appreciation for your original solution. It was exceptionally efficient and easy to use while reviewing thousands of files from field staff, so again many thanks from me and the team.

Comment: In that regard, I did notice one oddity. As we were running it against our directories, for times in the noon hour it would return 24, and for the midnight hour it would return 12. It was easy enough to resolve in the csv, but I was curious as to the root.
I carefully reviewed and retested your :24hr function at length, and I follow it better than I ever have, but I think it looks excellent so I'm not sure where it seemed to be adding the additional 12.

Comment: Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks again!

24:15,2023-04.20,24:15,2023-04.20,12-15 PM.docx
04:54,2023-04.20,12:30,2023-04.20,12-30 AM.docx
Expanded:
12412:15,2023-04.20,12412:15,2023-04.20,12-15 PM.docx
10404:54,2023-04.20,11212:30,2023-04.20,12-30 AM.docx